# Unexpected java.util.NoSuchElementException with BufferedReader

Tags: java, bufferedreader, java-stream

I am using the BufferedReader `lines()` method to get a specific line in a text file. Here is the code:

```
String line = reader.lines().filter(stuff -> stuff.startsWith(string)).findFirst().get(); // This is called inside of another method.
```

It works the first couple of times I call the method, then it only gives me a `NoSuchElementException` afterward. I have looked at the file and there indeed is a line that starts with the desired `string` variable.

I will give any more information if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `BufferedReader` is not reusable, as in, it can only traverse down the file, not up. When you call `.lines()` that last time, you have read the entire file, and the reader will be positioned at the end of the file. You may not be expecting it to have reached the end of the file yet, but as per the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#lines--):

> After execution of the terminal stream operation there are no guarantees that the reader will be at a specific position from which to read the next character or line.

To reliably call `.lines()` again, you need to instantiate the `BufferedReader` again. If you want to find the next occurrence in the file, use `.skip(X).findFirst()` on the subsequent calls.

Answer (score 0):

> It works the first time

So you've already read all the lines. So there are no more lines. So you can't read them.

Comment: @theTechopnoKid No, it works the first time only. After that you would have to reinitialize `reader`. It can't rewind of its own accord.

Comment: `.lines()` doesn't actually read all the lines. It is lazily populated, which means it will only read as much as the stream uses in the terminal operation. In this case, they did `findFirst()` which short-circuits the file read, and stops before the end of the file. However, the docs say that this isn't guaranteed.

Comment: @4castle I haven't said anything about `lines()`.